# Is there a way to quickly change the current in a superconducting loop?

Tags: electric-current, superconductivity

In rocket designs such as VASIMR, superconducting nozzles are frequently used to focus the resulting plasma jet. This leaves out the question of TVC control mandatory in chemical rocket engines, and an obvious way to do this is to adjust the magnetic nuzzle's field strength, e.g. make it slightly stronger on one side and weaker on the other. However, there doesn't appear to be a way to quickly adjust the current in a superconducting loop, ironically trivially easy in a normal electromagnet. Of course one can physically move the coil to change the magnetic field.

Is there some clever way to do this by circuit alone?

Answer (score 2):

A traditional method for changing the current in superconducting magnets (as [described on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_magnet#Operation)) is to have the [power supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_magnet#Power_supply) in the circuit in parallel with a "persistent switch" that can short-circuit it with a superconducting wire to run in [persistent mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_magnet#Persistent_mode)? When the switch is off, the power supply controls the current in the superconducting loop.  When you have the current you want, you short circuit the power supply with the superconductor.

Of course, there are limits on how fast you can change the current since the switching is done by heating and cooling a small piece of superconductor to change it between its superconducting and resistive state. The power supply needs to be carefully controlled when making the switch.

As noted in the question, one could change the magnetic field by moving the coil, but it is perhaps worth also pointing out that if two physically separated coils are in a single superconducting circuit, the one in the nozzle could be fixed while the current in the circuit is varied by adjusting the inductance of the other. This has been [proposed](https://doi.org/10.1088/1361-6668/ac549b) as a method for active stabilization of the current in superconducting magnets, but could in principle be used to change the current.